# How do I enable my back space button to go back a page on internet explorer

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

How do I enable my back space button to go back a page on internet explorer ... can someone please help me source out the solution to this quick fix problem

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 11 in Windows 10 by default uses <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> key to go one page back.

Possibly if you have set focus to a textbox, password box or `<input>` related elements, <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> key will only then erase the previous character.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you mean Edge based on a Chromium engine. If yes then backspace doesn't work as you want because some time ago peoples in Google decided to remove this useful shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's no such option for at [least](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/15357/windows-internet-explorer-11-keyboard-shortcuts) one browser.

> You can use Internet Explorer keyboard shortcuts to perform a lot of
> different tasks quickly or to work without a mouse. Not all shortcuts
> work in both Internet Explorer and Internet Explorer for the desktop.
> Top shortcuts To do this  Press this in Internet Explorer 11  Press
> this in Internet Explorer for the desktop
>
> Add current site to favorites
>
> Ctrl + D
>
> Crtl + D
>
> Close tab
>
> Ctrl + W
>
> Ctrl + W
>
> Go to your home page
>
> (Not available)
>
> Alt + Home
>
> Delete browsing history
>
> (Not available)
>
> Ctrl + Shift + Delete
>
> Get help & support
>
> F1
>
> F1
>
> Open browsing history
>
> (Not available)
>
> Ctrl + H
>
> Open a new tab
>
> Ctrl + T
>
> Ctrl + T
>
> Open a new InPrivate Browsing window
>
> Ctrl + Shift + P
>
> Ctrl + Shift + P
>
> Print the current page
>
> Ctrl + P
>
> Ctrl + P
>
> Refresh page
>
> F5
>
> F5
>
> Switch between tabs
>
> Ctrl + Tab
>
> Ctrl + Tab
>
> View the app commands (address bar, frequent sites, etc.)
>
> Alt + D
>
> (Not available)
>
> View downloads
>
> Ctrl + J
>
> Ctrl + J

what is your exact browser and exact version number?